# how to display alert to the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

When I try to run the following code, nothing happens. When I debug in Visual Studio Code, it shows no error but in the browser nothing happens. I am trying to connect to a database. If I use `console.log` it works fine.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./mybook.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE);

    let sql = 'SELECT option FROM beginner where option ="verb to be";';

    db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if(typeof window !== "undefined")
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            window.alert(row.option);
        });
    });
```

Comment: There are no users or browsers on the Node side. If you just want to log data, use `console.log`, and the related info/warn/error functions, but it sounds like you're trying to just straight up load this in a browser, in which case: that's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work in the browser because a web browser doesn't define a `require` function- the browser has no SQL database. You might be interested in [Indexed DB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), which is similar to SQL, stores data, and works in the browser.

Your code also doesn't work in Node.JS- the concept of a `window` is browser-specific. Use `console.log` instead of `window.alert` to get it to run in Node.JS.

Comment: thank you for your comment, but what about document.write it also does not work.the console.log shows result when I am in vscode but does not show result in the browser. I need a way to display a message to the user

Comment: This code will not run in the browser because you cannot do SQL operations in the browser.